# How to draw Yaxis label in highcharts

Tags: label, highcharts, renderer

Is there any way to draw Yaxis lable using highcharts/highstock api? The value of the label will be the end value of the series. The color will be the same color of the series.

I found there is a renderer api, but is seems it is difficult to know the exact position of the point.

[image: yaxis label]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an older example that uses the renderer function:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/4FrGG/4/

```
function(chart){
    $(chart.series).each(function(i, serie){
        //to get the appropraite 'y' position
        var point = serie.data[serie.data.length-1];
        chart.renderer.text(
            //the text to render
            '<span style="font-weight:bold;color:' + serie.color + ';">' + serie.name + '</span>',
            //the 'x' position
            chart.plotLeft+chart.plotWidth+5,
            //the 'y' position
            chart.plotTop + point.plotY+3).add()
    });
});
```

You could also do it by using data labels, enabled for only the last data point:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/zXLZA/0/

You could also do it now by using the 'tickPositions' property, and then the formatter function on the axis labels

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter